# Select column in list of sublists

Tags: python, list

I have a list which contains sublists of three strings:

Example:

```
data=[
      [' 2.131e+02', ' 2.186e+02', '-9.073e+00'],
      [' 6.205e+01', ' 6.633e+01', '-1.708e+01'],
      ['-4.220e-01', '-7.210e-02', '-5.062e-01']
     ]
```

Ho can I select a column?

I can select `data[0]` which would be the first row, but I am not able to select a column.
I thought the following would select the elements of the first column `data[:][0]` but it selects again the first row?

Comment: `[l[0] for l in data]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve what you want with:

```
[x[0] for x in data]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data=[
      [' 2.131e+02', ' 2.186e+02', '-9.073e+00'],
      [' 6.205e+01', ' 6.633e+01', '-1.708e+01'],
      ['-4.220e-01', '-7.210e-02', '-5.062e-01']
     ]

def get_column(matrix, i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]
    
print(get_column(data, 1))
```

`i` is the index of the column that you want to get.